# How can I bind attribute value of different HTML elements using single custom attribute directive in Angular 7?

Tags: angular, angular7

I am trying to implement Lazy loading of images using Intersection Observaber API.

Scenario:
I have array of images in component.ts.
I have created directive to implement Intersection Observable API.
I am using attribute directive  selector in  HTML element.
I am taking ElementRef using selector and then using it to set "src" as when image comes into viewing area.

Requirement I am stuck at:

I want to show intersection ratio of image from Viewport respective in different HTML element tag.
I am using Angular material progress bar to update the intersection ratio.
As  is different element from where attribute directive selector is used, how can I bind the value of progress bar dynamically as I am fetching the value during loading of images?

**Directive.ts**

```js
@HostBinding('attr.src') imageSrc = null;
@Input() src: string;
@HostBinding('attr.value') intersectionValue;
thresholdSet = [];
observerOptions = {
    root: null,
    rootMargin: "0px",
    threshold: []
  };

constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {
    this.generateThreshold();
  }

generateThreshold() {
    for (let i = 0; i <= 1.0; i += 0.01) {
      this.thresholdSet.push(i);
    }
  }

ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.lazyLoadImage()
}

lazyLoadImage() {    
    this.observerOptions.threshold = this.thresholdSet;
    const observe = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {     
      entries.forEach(entry => {
        let box = entry.target;
        let visibleRatio = (Math.floor(entry.intersectionRatio * 100)) + "%";        
        if (entry.isIntersecting) {
          this.imageSrc = this.src;
        }
      })
    }, this.observerOptions)

    observe.observe(this.elementRef.nativeElement);
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<mat-card  class="example-card outerDiv" *ngFor="let dummy of dummydata; trackBy: trackIndex">
  <mat-card-header>
    <mat-card-title>
      {{dummy.name}}
    </mat-card-title>

  </mat-card-header>
  <img appLazyLoading [src]="dummy.image" alt="image description" class="imageElement">
  <br>
  <mat-progress-bar class="bottomRight" mode="determinate" [value]='intersectionValue'></mat-progress-bar>

</mat-card>
```

How can I bind value attribute of `<mat-progress-bar>` as I am using directive selector in `<img>` tag, If I use selector in root element `<mat-card>` tag, lazy loading is not working.
Please can anyone help?